# Different template parts when on different pages

Tags: pages, templates, homepage, single

I need to get different template parts when locating on different pages, for e.g. Homepage.

```
<?php if (is_home()) {
  get_template_part( 'partials/hp-header' )
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'partials/single-page-header' )};
?>
```

Comment: What's your question? What's not working and the expected outcome?

Comment: The code seems to not work for me, so I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Where do you put the code - in what template? And how does it not working - the template part being loaded is not the right one? Are you sure the template parts (e.g. `partials/hp-header.php`) exist? And how about trying a simple `echo` test - `if ( is_home() ) echo 'hp-header'; else echo 'single-page-header';` ?